# Automate adding daily-updated PivotTable data to a new cell in a table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to automate Excel report following the [tutorial](http://blog.velingeorgiev.pro/automated-excel-report-task-scheduler-and-simple-vba-functions) of Velin Georgiev.

It's a daily report, and I have a table where I add a total value from everyday-updated PivotTable into a new cell (both Pivot and standard tables are on the same worksheet).

In standard table the column **Date** contains "today" date and **Total** takes data from the PivotTable. Every day this table should increase on one row.

[image]

So far it was done manually. Is it possible to do it with VBA and how?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would another pivot table be able to summarise by date?

Answer (score 0):

Your case seems to be an application of a broader idea in excel - getting to the bottom end of a block of information. There are a few different methods (summarised [here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)) each with their own pros and cons.

The one that is simplest for your case is probably .End. I don't know the exact structure of your sheet, but something like the following

```
Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1).Copy
```

will copy the cell in the penultimate row of Column A of your table (just before "TOTAL" - if you have subtotals, make it -2, or whatever).

Then, to copy to your standard table, do something like

```
 Range("F" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

where "F" is the second column of your table (or wherever you want to paste it).

Answer (score 0):

That's how I've solved the issue (many thanks to people who posted the similar questions & solution to them in internet):

```
Sub VlookupFunction()

   Dim S_Name As String
   Dim Lookup_Range As Range  
   Dim S_Value As Single

   Dim c As Long 'column
   Dim r As Long 'row

   S_Name = "OpenState"
   Set Lookup_Range = Range("A1:B10")

   S_Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(S_Name, Lookup_Range, 2, False)

With Sheet1

  r = .Columns(3).Find(what:="", after:=.Cells(14, 3)).Row
    .Cells(r, 3) = Date 'today 

  r = .Columns(4).Find(what:="", after:=.Cells(14, 4)).Row
    .Cells(r, 4) = S_Value

End With

End Sub
```